# JS calling a function witin a function with date formatting

Tags: javascript, function, date

I am trying to call a function `testAvailability` from within `unavailableDays`.  I need to format the date as a string in `selDate` using `dd-MM-yyyy` format.  I think I am either not calling the function properly or there is a problem with my date formatting or both.

Any thoughts?

```
function unavailableDays(days) {
    var i = Date.now();
    var d;
    var checkit 
    var unavailableDates = [];
    var j = i + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    while(i < j) {
        d = new Date(i);

        //add an if then statement here, if true push the date else no
        checkit = testAvailability("'" + d.getDate() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + (d.getYear() + 1900) + "'");
        if(checkit ===  true) {
            unavailableDates.push(d.getDate() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + (d.getYear() + 1900));
            i += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        } else {
            i += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        }
    }
    return unavailableDates;
}

var numOfDays = 60;
var populated = unavailableDays(numOfDays);

...


function testAvailability(selDate) {

    // Find the selected service duration (it is going to 
    // be send within the "postData" object).
    var selServiceDuration = 15; // Default value of duration (in minutes).
    $.each(GlobalVariables.availableServices, function(index, service) {
        if (service['id'] == $('#select-service').val()) {
            selServiceDuration = service['duration']; 
        }
    });

    // If the manage mode is true then the appointment's start 
    // date should return as available too.
    var appointmentId = (FrontendBook.manageMode) 
            ? GlobalVariables.appointmentData['id'] : undefined;

    var postData = {
        'service_id': $('#select-service').val(),
        'provider_id': $('#select-provider').val(),
        'selected_date': selDate,
        'service_duration': selServiceDuration,
        'manage_mode': FrontendBook.manageMode,
        'appointment_id': appointmentId
    };

    // Make ajax post request and get the available hours.
    var ajaxurl = GlobalVariables.baseUrl + 'appointments/ajax_get_available_hours';
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, postData, function(response) {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        console.log('Get Available Hours JSON Response:', response);
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if (!GeneralFunctions.handleAjaxExceptions(response));

        // The response tells me if the date is booked (true) or not. 
        if (response.length > 0) {
           return false;
        } else {
           return true;
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

Comment: Does `testAvailability` have a `return` statement that returns the success or failure?

Comment: Don't use `d.getYear() + 1900`, use `d.getFullYear()`.

Comment: Yes,  it is a true/false.  Thanks

Comment: @Barmar & cravaus: no, it's not. The `testAvailability` function does not return anything.

Comment: `testAvailability` uses AJAX, which is asynchronous. It returns immediately, not when the AJAX call is completed.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `testAvailability()` check for the date string in the `unavailableDates` array. You are testing with quotes, but you are recording the string without quotes, so there's no match.

```
var datestr;
// ..

while(i < j) {
    d = new Date(i);
    datestr = "" + d.getDate() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + (d.getYear() + 1900);

    if (testAvailability(datestr) === true) unavailableDates.push(datestr);
    i += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

EDIT after OP posted relevant code:

Here's your problem: the `testAvailability` function doesn't return a boolean (or anything for that matter), it's an asynchronous function. Your code can't possibly work.

Comment: I see your concern.  It is different.  The full function is below:

Comment: Now that you posted the relevant code, see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Move all that date formatting to single variable:

```
while (i < j) {
    d = new Date(i);
    var newDate = d.getDate() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + (d.getYear() + 1900);
```

Also I don't think you need `'` around parameter of function:

```
testAvailability(newDate);
```

Comment: op is formatting date created inside `while` loop. So he can't format it outside the loop. Also he's sending formatted date as string to `testAvailability` so he needs those quotes.